# Return a list from Entity Framework, based on string parameter

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a database first Entity Framework setup. Usually, I create procedures like this, to return a list of a defined object in my model.

```
    public List<Employees> GetEmployees()
    {
        var tables = _crmContext.Employees.ToList();

        return tables;
    }
```

That works fine but the case I can't figure out, it different. I want to return a list of an object in the entity framework model, based on a parameter passed to the procedure.
I was trying something like this, but it's not working and I also don't know if is the right approach.

```
    public List<T> GetValuesFromTable(string table)
    {
        var results = _crmContext."table".ToList();

        return results;
    }
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

I think the Generic Repository Pattern is what you're looking for. In this way, you can call all the tables you have given type with a single method. [Example](https://codewithshadman.com/repository-pattern-csharp/)

Repository.cs

```
public class Repository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    protected readonly DbContext Context;

    public Repository(DbContext context)
    {
        this.Context = context;
    }

    public IEnumerable<TEntity> GetAll()
    {
        return Context.Set<TEntity>().ToList();
    }
 }
```

IRepository.cs

```
public interface IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{        
    IEnumerable<TEntity>GetAll();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering :)

I don't think I see this helping me. It must be that I don't get it right. 

I need to return all rows from a the table I am passing as a parameter. The context is already defined. What will change is the result depending on the specific table I ask.